# In Spring new() object instance cannot use afterProperties set attributes

Tags: java

I use Spring boot 2.

In class **DebugServerBizChannelHandlerManager** I want to use Class
**DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler** with new()， but the attribute in the instance is always null.

How can I set attribute with new() method.

DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler:

```
public class DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        this.platformEnum = PlatformEnum.DebugServer;
        this.mapInfo = ChannelThingMapInfoFactory.getInstance(platformEnum);
    }
}
```

DebugServerBizChannelHandlerManager:

```
public class DebugServerBizChannelHandlerManager extends AbstractChannelHandlerManager {



    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline tcpHandler(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
        pipeline
                .addLast(new DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler())
```

Comment: Baceuse afterPropertiesSet() is never called. Inject DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler 
 into DebugServerBizChannelHandlerManager and then add it to the pipeline.

Comment: @marc If I want multiple DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler injected to the DebugServerBizChannelHandlerManager, I must add @Scope("prototype") to the DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler?

Comment: If you use @Scope("prototype"), every time you inject the handler Spring will create a new instance. Another approach is to create multiple handler classes and inject them in the pipeline.

Comment: @marc how to inject them in the pipline?  Thank you.

Comment: Using @ Autowired as @stacker answered. Please upvote if useful :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In spring-boot you are supposed to use annotations to declare your classes as components or services.

```
@Component
public class DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler()
```

To use this class by injection the @Autowired annotation is required:

```
@Component
public class DebugServerBizChannelHandlerManager extends AbstractChannelHandlerManager {

    @Autowired
    DebugServerDeviceStatusHandler statusHandler;

    @Override
    public ChannelPipeline tcpHandler(ChannelPipeline pipeline) {
        pipeline
                .addLast(statusHandler)
```

and don't forget to enable and configure component scan.
For further explanation of concepts see the [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation)